# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \pi}\left(\frac{1}{x-\pi}\right)\int_{\pi}^{x}\frac{\cos t}{1-\cos t}\,dt.$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to \pi}\left(\frac{1}{x-\pi}\right)\int_{\pi}^{x}\frac{\cos t}{1-\cos t}\,dt.$$

I am stuck on this problem. I have tried in many ways to connect calculus theorems but I am not being able to. Can someone give me a direction.

Comment: Hint: can you apply the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Note that $\cos \pi = -1$.  What would $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{1}{x-\pi}\int_{\pi}^{x}\frac{-1}{1-(-1)}\,dt$ give?

Comment: Could you add the work you've done, in a few of the ways you've tried to connect calculus theorems?  What made you conclude you are not able "to connect calculus theorems  At the very least, please include statements of the theorems you've considered, as what you have shared with us, thus far, regarding your "efforts" is not at all clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $F(x)$ be an antiderivative of your integrand.  Then the limit is:

$$= \lim_{x\to \pi} \frac{F(x)-F(\pi)}{x-\pi} = F'(\pi) =
\frac{\cos\pi}{1-\cos \pi} = \frac{-1}{2}. $$

Comment: $F(x)=\int_\pi^x\frac{\cos t}{1-\cos t}$ *is* an antiderivative over $(0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite the expression as $$\frac{\int_{\pi}^{x}{\frac{\cos{t}}{1-\cos{t}}dt}}{\pi-x}$$ and observe that both the numerator and denominator approach $0$ as $x$ approaches $\pi$. Then apply L'Hôpital's rule (use the fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate the derivative of the numerator).

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule is probably not necessary since this fits literally the definition of the derivative (using a suitable definition of $F(x)$).

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to \pi}\left(\frac{1}{x-\pi}\right)\int_{\pi}^{x}\frac{\cos t}{1-\cos t}\,dt$$

$$=\lim_{x\to \pi}\left(\frac{\int_{\pi}^{x}\frac{\cos t}{1-\cos t}\,dt}{x-\pi}\right)$$

Using L' Hospital rule,

$$=\lim_{x\to \pi}\left(\frac{\frac{\cos x}{1-\cos x}}{1}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\cos \pi}{1-\cos\pi}=\frac{-1}{2}$$